# Java List.add() method adds an modifiable object

Tags: java, c++

I am just recently switching from C++ to Java. I am converting a piece of C++ code to java. The codes basically adds a 1-d vector to a 2-d one, then modify the 1-d vector, and it doesn't change the 2-d one in C++.  However, when I implemented this in Java, it seems modifying 1-d List will modify the 2-d List. Can anyone give me some terminologies for this so I can learn more about Java, and its difference from C++ in this aspect? Thanks.

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printVec(vector<vector<int>> &vec) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); ++j) {
                        cout << vec[i][j] << "\t";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }
}

int main() {
        vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
        vector<vector<int>> b;
        b.push_back(a);

        printVec(b);

        a.pop_back();
        printVec(b);
}
```

Output:

```
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list2.add(list);
        System.out.println(list2);

        list.remove(1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }
}
```

Output:

> [[2, 3, 4]] [[2, 4]]

Comment: C++ has strong value semantics, Java does not (pass by value, pass by reference, whatever you want to call it). If you understand C++, you can almost pretend like every Java object (which you allocate by writing `new Something();`) is a shared_ptr.

Comment: Your C++ code is copying the list, but the Java code adds reference to list to list2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the inner `List` to be modified, you just need to copy it first when adding `list` to `list2` by using `ArrayList`'s copy-constructor:

```
list2.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
```

This occurs because Java passes objects by value (shallow copy), and any modification to mutable references will be reflected in your `List`, as you've seen by the output. However, after performing a copy, the output is the following:

```
[[2, 3, 4]]
[[2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: I know this is how to change it, but want to learn deeper about the difference of the two languages. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You mean java passes by reference?

Comment: No, Java passes by value, but if the *reference* is mutable, then it can still be modified.  To prevent modification, you need to perform a *deep copy* (in your case, as I believe `Integer` is immutable).  And unfortunately I don't know enough C++ to tell you how it differs from Java, but I'm sure many websites list differences.

Comment: @JacobG. is right. see link https://dzone.com/articles/java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @JacobG. the stricter way to say it in case of references would be *pass by value of the reference*